# PC doesn't select right monitor sometimes

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I have an ACER LCD monitor with Intel G33/G31 display chipset. The preferred resolution for monitor is 1440x900.

The drivers for both monitor and display are correctly installed and displayed in Device Manager section.

However, I have observed, sometimes, in Display properties, my PC shows `Display Device on: VGA` instead of `Display Device on: Acer` , and when that happens, the resolution becomes distorted and I am unable to switch back to 1440x900.

However, this problem resolves itself automatically sometimes between reboots.

Any idea what's going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I seem to have found the solution to it. It turns out that if the VGA cable is not tightly plugged into computer, this can happen. Tightening the cable solved the problem.